# Regex check from a link

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a link that is

```
dashboard/permissions?page=2
```

so in javascript i want check if this link's last has "?page=2"  or not

if has then remove it

Note: here ?page=2  2 is changeable

so how to do it in javascript

Comment: Please google `querystring javascript`.

Comment: `dashboard/permissions?page=2.replace(/\?page=\d+$/, "")`

Answer (score 0):

```
var testStr = document.URL;
console.log(testStr.match(/\?page=\d+/) !== null);
```

Comment: @SuperScript While this answer is a bit bare in terms of explanation, it is still valid.

Comment: @shruggernaut: Tiny code snippets are better as comments. It looks like the right code; explain a little on what it does and you'll be good.

Comment: @SuperScript They're better as comments when they are intended as a comment, perhaps on somebody else's answer, but if this were posted as a comment on the question, you could rest assured that somebody might come along and request that they post it as an answer.

Comment: @shruggernaut: while they work, code-only answers are not likely to be useful to future users.  [See](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/2619939) [these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95470/241819) [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146865/241819) posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex: `\?page=\d+`:

```js
var url = 'dashboard/permissions?page=2';
alert(url.match(/\?page=\d+/));
```

And to remove it :

```
if(url.match(/\?page=\d+/)!==null) {
    url=url.replace(/\?page=\d+/, "");
    alert(url);
}
//returns "dashboard/permissions"
```